# How to provide power to a micro controller in a high voltage (180V DC) circuit?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design

I have a 230V AC to ~180V DC circuit to drive a DC motor and need to power a micro controller board with 5V DC in order to provide a PWM signal.

Originally I thought of simply recycling a USB mains adapter but since most/all of those are isolated from the mains and the motors power supply is not I assume there zero reference is going to be incompatible.

Whats the simplest way to provide a compatible (needs to control MOSFET gate in high voltage circuit) low voltage DC?

Comment: While Alex's solution fixed my problem I figured I'd mention for the benefit of anyone else that another alternative that I was looking into and probably would have been a workable solution was using a shunt regulator.

Comment: The downside you might encounter with your USB charger is Y cap leakage since you are shifting your minus reference between the two. If you are not going to interface and measure something, you won’t see this. Are you going for high side driving 5 V _above_ your 180 Vdc?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly then I'm just going for low side (both sharing same zero).

Comment: Then you should have no issues. Please report back how it went.

Comment: I will report back with an edit to the original question with my results once I have the micro board running from the same 230V AC plug as the motor and switching the MOSFET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your idea of the USB mains adapter and just tie the ground pin of the mains adapter output (or the ground of the microcontroller) to the ground of the 180V DC circuit. If your MOSFET is set up correctly, it should work properly.

Comment: It was so obvious - I was totally overthinking things (better that than the alternative on mains circuits)! Haven't driven the MOSFET yet but I have tested the voltages with a multi meter after simply tying the two DC zero references and it worked a treat with nothing going pop! - Thanks.